# NGRX Nested state update child nested data

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, entity, ngrx

Hey guys I'm trying to implement an entity that has another entity inside the interface. Sorry for may bad English. I'm trying to update the child entity, but it's not working. I don't know if there is something wrong with the code or if it's a proper way of doing it.

Is it good to do a nested state in NgRx? Sorry for by bad English. I'm really beginner in using NgRx and angular

[image]

```
// in here im passing the id of parent and the data i want to update in nested child data
export const TestUpdate = createAction(
  '[testtttt] Load WorkFromHomes Description Success',
  props<{ id: number; WorkFromHomeDescription }>()
);

export interface WorkFromHomeDescription {
  id: number;
  wfmId: number;
  day: Date;
  awaDescription: string;
  startTime: string;
  endTime: string;
  targetDeliverables: string;
  accomplishment: string;
  evidence: string;
  createdBy?: any;
  dateCreated?: any;
  modifiedBy: number;
  dateModified: Date;
  employeeId: number;
}

export interface WorkFromHome {
  id: number;
  wfmStart: Date;
  wfmEnd: Date;
  employeeId: number;
  immediateSupervisorId: number;
  vpId: number;
  isApprove: boolean;
  createdBy?: any;
  dateCreated?: any;
  modifiedBy: number;
  dateModified: Date;
  workFromHomeDescriptions: EntityState<WorkFromHomeDescription>;
}

export interface WorkFromHomeState extends EntityState<WorkFromHome> {
  loaded: boolean;
  loading: boolean;
  error: string | null;
}

export const adapter: EntityAdapter<WorkFromHome> = createEntityAdapter<WorkFromHome>();
export const adapterWorkDesc: EntityAdapter<WorkFromHomeDescription> = createEntityAdapter<WorkFromHomeDescription>();
export const initialState: WorkFromHomeState = adapter.getInitialState({
  loaded: false,
  loading: false,
  error: null,
});
export const WorkFromHomeReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(WorkFromHomeAction.test, (state, action) => {
    const workdata = action.WorkFromHomeDescription;
    return adapter.mapOne(
      {
        id: action.id,
        map: data => ({
          ...data,
          workFromHomeDescriptions: adapterWorkDesc.updateOne(
            {
              id: workdata.id,
              ...workdata,
            },
            data.workFromHomeDescriptions
          ),
        }),
      },
      state
    );
  })
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm biased but I would encourage you to use [ngrx-immer](https://github.com/timdeschryver/ngrx-immer) (I'm the author). With it you will be able to just update your state.